# Django HTML templates - storing a JSON object somewhere on the page

Tags: jquery, json, django

I know it's not a stackoverflow-like question in some way, but please don't ban me on this. I really need a best-practice advice on this.

I have a Django view rendering a table on an HTML template.
My goal is to validate user input data on client side and part of validation has to do with complex data analysis which takes into account data that is not rendered in the table. I cannot use user-defined attributes because I have a filter on the table hiding rows depending on filter conditions, and if the filter is not empty, my data validation will not be correct based on parsing all table rows.

**UPDATE:** For this reason, I pass JSON object from my Django view to HTML template. But the problem is that I fail to pass it to external JS file.

For example, let's say I have an editable table as specified below.

```
<tbody json_failed_attempt = {{json_object}}>
    {% for vendor in vendors_table %}
    <tr>
        <td class = 'click_this_row'>
            {{vendor.legal_entity.name}}
        </td>
     </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

JQuery

```
$('td.click_this_row').on('change', function()
    {
         // HOW SHOULD I PARSE THROUGH THE JSON ???
         // This alert outputs this:
         // "[{"model":"
         alert ($('#vendorsTable tbody').attr('legal_entities_json'))
    }
```

Django view:

```
def vendors(request):

    vendors_table = Vendors.objects.all()
    legal_entities_queryset = LegalEntities.objects.all()
    legal_entities_json = serializers.serialize('json', legal_entities_queryset, fields=('inn', 'kpp'))

    return render_to_response('vendors/vendors_list.html',
                             {'vendors_table':vendors_table, 
                              'legal_entities_json' : legal_entities_json},
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Is this method possible ? And if yes, why can't I use parseJSON here ? And how should the loop look like ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `JSON.parse` in your javascript:

```
JSON.parse($('#vendorsTable tbody').attr('legal_entities_json'))
```

Another approach is to create javascript variable and assign JSON object to it (since JSON is a valid javascript object). In your template:

```
<script>
var data = {{ json_object }};
</script>
```

and then use `data` variable in your external JS file.

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan Do you set `data ` variable before including external JS script ? You could also try to set `data` as `window` object attribute: `window.my_data = {{ json_object }};`

Comment: thank you, both methods work now. The only question that bothers me is the fact that the user can see the data if they view the page source. Doesn't that constitute a satety issue in a way ?

Comment: @EdgarNavasardyan I don't think that it constitute a safety issue. Django has default protection from this kind of issues. https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/security/#cross-site-scripting-xss-protection